# How do I download to an external hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive, data-transfer

I have a very large file to download, and I want to download it directly to an external hard drive and not to the download folder on my c: drive.
Is there a way I can do this? There only appears to be two options, open or download.
I can only find answers here for extracting zip files, not for downloading directly.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot showing the screen with the two options? Also, which browser are you using, which OS X version?

Comment: Also, Macs don't have a C: drive... are you actually on a Mac?

Answer (score 3):

You didn't specify which browser you are using, so I assume Safari. Two options come to mind:

- Right-click on the file you want to download and download directly to a destination you select
- Open Safari Preferences (in the Safari menu) and select a different download destination in the General tab